# How can I fill missing dates with the last entry in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the below data:

```
data = [{"id":1,"date":" 1-1-2001","f1":1,"f2":0,"f3":1},{"id":1,"date":" 2-1-2001","f1":2,"f2":1,"f3":1},{"id":1,"date":" 3-1-2001","f1":3,"f2":1,"f3":1},{"id":2,"date":" 1-1-2001","f1":1,"f2":0,"f3":1},{"id":2,"date":" 3-1-2001","f1":3,"f2":2,"f3":1},{"id":3,"date":" 1-1-2001","f1":1,"f2":0,"f3":1},{"id":3,"date":" 2-1-2001","f1":5,"f2":3,"f3":3}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        date  f1  f2  f3  id
0   1-1-2001   1   0   1   1
1   3-1-2001   2   1   1   1
2   4-1-2001   3   1   1   1
3   1-1-2001   1   0   1   2
4   4-1-2001   3   2   1   2
5   1-1-2001   1   0   1   3
6   3-1-2001   5   3   3   3
```

In the above data, each row should be identified with the "id" label, but both id's 2 and 3 are missing entries from a date which has entries for ID 1. Is there a simple way I can create these rows with dates that other ID's have, but and fill them with their previous entry? The desired output is:

```
        date  f1  f2  f3  id
0   1-1-2001   1   0   1   1
1   3-1-2001   2   1   1   1
2   4-1-2001   3   1   1   1
3   1-1-2001   1   0   1   2
4   3-1-2001   1   0   1   2
5   4-1-2001   3   2   1   2
6   1-1-2001   1   0   1   3
7   3-1-2001   5   3   3   3
8   4-1-2001   5   3   3   3
```

Please keep in mind I don't want to create rows for dates that don't exist in the dataset. Essentially, if a date already exists in my "date" column, I want to ensure that there is a row for that date for each ID. For example, if ID 101 has an entry for the 3rd of January but ID 103 doesn't, I'd like to create a row for ID 103, 3rd of January which fills with the feature data from its previous datapoint (2nd of January, or whatever the previous date in the dataset is).

I hope my question is clear enough. If not I am happy to clarify in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) using the [`from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product) method.

Use this to reindex your `DataFrame` then use `DataFrame.ffill` to fill in the NaN values.

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['date'].unique(), df['id'].unique()],
                                 names=['date', 'id'])

df_fixed = df.set_index(['date', 'id']).reindex(idx).reset_index().sort_values('id').ffill()

df_fixed = df_fixed.loc[:, df.columns].astype(df.dtypes)
```

[out]

```
       date  f1  f2  f3  id
0  1-1-2001   1   0   1   1
3  3-1-2001   2   1   1   1
6  4-1-2001   3   1   1   1
1  1-1-2001   1   0   1   2
4  3-1-2001   1   0   1   2
7  4-1-2001   3   2   1   2
2  1-1-2001   1   0   1   3
5  3-1-2001   5   3   3   3
8  4-1-2001   5   3   3   3
```

Comment: This is incorrect output if I compare it to the OP's expected output.

Comment: @Erfan Fixed column order and dtype to better reflect OP expected output

Comment: Your answer is correct since I run your code, but the output your pasted here is incorrect. Date 4-1-2001 is missing instead of 2-1-2001

Comment: I get correct output if I add `df_fixed = df_fixed.loc[:, df.columns].astype(df.dtypes).reset_index(drop=True)` in the last line

Comment: @Erfan The dict OP provided does not reflect the DataFrame printed above. I updated my answer to use the printed df instead of the `data` variable

Comment: Ah I see, I didnt use the dict, I used `pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')`